# FOSUserBundle override template

Tags: php, twig, fosuserbundle

i'm very new to symfony and i'm stuck on an error.
I already searched for this over and over again but i didn't find any fix:
I installed the FOSUserBundle and i want to override layout.html.twig template to be my homepage of the website. I created a new bundle, made it a child of FOSUserBundle  :

```
namespace Emag\UserBundle;  
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;  
class UserBundle extends Bundle {  
    public function getParent(){  
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
}  
}
```

I made a new file in the src/Emag/UserBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig and a new controller

```
class HomeController extends Controller {

public function homeAction()
{

    return $this->render('UserBundle\layout.html.twig');

}
```

}
but i get this error:
**Unable to find template   "UserBundle\layout.html.twig".**
here's also my routing.yml file:

```
emag_magazine_homepage:
path:     /emag
defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Home:home }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the correct namespace; EMAGUserBundle not UserBundle inside your routing file and in the homeAction to get your code well organised,

and then you have to change :

```
return $this->render('EmagUserBundle\layout.html.twig');
```

to

```
return $this->render('EmagUserBundle:layout.html.twig');
```